# .htaccess not blocking specified user agent

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, user-agent

**UPDATE**
I found the Firefox addon: User Agent Switcher which allows me to test with a different user agent. Surprise, it blocked the user agent as it should. I wonder why the 12 or so requests which took place after my first block attempt via `.htaccess` somehow slipped in. Were the page requests already in process? Oh well, at least they are working.

---

In my `.htaccess` I have a php script that checks for offending user agent strings and dynamically writes to `.htaccess` a `RewriteCond` to immediately block the user agent.

I tried to block the agent `Mozilla/5.0 (Auto Shell Spider)` by writing the following condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Mozilla/5\.0\ \(Auto\ Shell\ Spider\)).*$ [NC]` but my log showed the user agent continued to access pages (another 10+ over the next 2 seconds). I've tested the rule with `preg_match()` and it matches and therefore should block the user agent. What is happening? 
I am under the impression that I don't need an `AND` in the `RewriteCond` since each has its own `RewriteRule`. I don't believe there is caching of `.htaccess` - changes should take effect immediately. Is php regex different from htaccess?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a more complete set of `.htaccess` instructions:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

# Block spiders: 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Baiduspider|360Spider|Sogou|Sosospider|Yandex|NaverBot|Yeti|moget|ichiro|RedBot|AhrefsBot|xovibot).*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
Deny from 59.61.184.100
Deny from 59.152.240.71

# Block User Agent -  NOT WORKING?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Mozilla/5\.0\ \(Auto\ Shell\ Spider\)).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

When using php preg_match,

```
$text =  "Mozilla/5.0 (Auto Shell Spider)";
preg_match('`^.*(Mozilla/5\.0\ \(Auto\ Shell\ Spider\)).*$`', $text, $acell);    
echo "<pre>";var_dump($acell);echo "</pre>";
```

I get a match as follows:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Auto Shell Spider)' (length=31)
  1 => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Auto Shell Spider)' (length=31)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reordering your rules like this:

```
Deny from 59.61.184.100
Deny from 59.152.240.71

RewriteEngine On

# Block spiders: 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Baiduspider|360Spider|Sogou|Sosospider|Yandex|NaverBot|Yeti|moget|ichiro|RedBot|AhrefsBot|xovibot).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]

# Block User Agent -  NOT WORKING?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Mozilla/5\.0 \(Auto Shell Spider\)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you explain why this will have the desired result? My script simply appends the new RewriteRule each time it finds a new offender. It is more complicated to insert the new rules into the middle of .htaccess, plus it is difficult to debug to see if the change is effective. Before going through the extra work, it would be helpful to understand why the original does not work. I understand that .htaccess processes commands in order but I don't understand how the current order would conflict. Thanks.

Comment: I found the Firefox addon: User Agent Switcher which allows me to test with a different user agent. Surprise, it blocked the user agent as it should. I wonder why the 12 or so requests which took place after my first block attempt somehow slipped in. Caching? Timing (the requests were already in process)? Anyway, I will use your answer as good advice regardless. Thank you.

Comment: htaccess isn't cached unless you're using some proxy in front or some other CMS framework. Any change made in .htaccess is effective immediately otherwise but browsers can also cache results sometimes.